# Voltage Offset and Scaling from DAC to current driver

Tags: level-shifting, 4-20ma

I have a DAC with an output of 0-4.096V that I need to convert to 4-20mA. I am planning to use the XTR111 which converts 0-5VDC to 0-20mA.  To use the full range of the DAC (ie 0-4.096V = 4-20mA), I want to shift the DAC output up by 1V so that I feed 1-5VDC into the XTR111.  How would I achieve this?